# Using the TCL interpreter repeatedly inside a C program

Tags: c, tcl

I wish to use a c program repeatedly run the TCL interpreter many times. For reasons that are complicated, I need this to be a pure C program and not something that is embedded as a shared object. As an example, I wish to run this simple tcl program, tryMe.tcl, twice:

```
prtstr "Test from tryMe.tcl"
```

The prtstr is a TCL function that I have written that for right now just writes to stdout. Below is the c code that is attempting to interpret the tryMe.tcl program twice.

I compile the program below like this under linux:

```
$ gcc -c try.c; gcc -o try try.o -ltcl;
```

and run it like this:

```
$ ./try tryMe.tcl
```

And I get zero output.  What am I doing wrong? Also are there steps required to reset the tcl interpreter so that it will be fresh each time.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <tcl/tcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int PrintStrObjCmd(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])
{
  char     *str;
  int      len;
  Tcl_Obj *objPtr;
  int i;
  if (objc != 2) {
    Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "value");
   return TCL_ERROR;
  }
  objPtr = objv[1];

  str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objPtr, &len);
  if (str[0] == '\0')
    return TCL_ERROR;

  printf("len: %d, str: %s\n", len, str);
  return TCL_OK;
}

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp* interp)
{
  if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
    return TCL_ERROR;
  Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp,"prtstr", PrintStrObjCmd, (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
  return TCL_OK;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *cmd = NULL;
  Tcl_Interp * interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();

  Tcl_AppInit(interp);

  asprintf(&cmd, "%s -x -y -z", argv[1]);
  Tcl_Eval(interp, cmd);
  free(cmd);
  asprintf(&cmd, "%s -q -r -s 2", argv[1]);
  Tcl_Eval(interp, cmd);
  exit(0);
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Besides Tcl, users may want to explore the Pawn scripting language, which is also small and is easily embedded. I looked at Tcl for something like, but felt Pawn was a better fit. Lua is another language that is also used in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer to TCLer's Wiki.  That helped.  I didn't understand that the `script` in `Tcl_Eval(interp,script)` was not a file name but a character string containing a tcl program.  So this program uses `TCL_Evalfile()` I also wanted to be able to pass command line arguments to the tcl program.  I found out how but diving into the TCL source for Tcl_MainEx().   Below is a program that does what I want.  Also I discovered that calling `Tcl_EvalFile` more than one does retains the state so if I want a fresh value of the interpreter, I'll have to delete the old one and create a new one everytime.

```
#include <tcl/tcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int PrintStrObjCmd(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])
{
  char     *str;
  int      len;
  Tcl_Obj *objPtr;
  int i;
  if (objc != 2) {
    Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "value");
    return TCL_ERROR;
  }
  objPtr = objv[1];

  str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objPtr, &len);
  if (str[0] == '\0')
    return TCL_ERROR;

  printf("len: %d, str: %s\n", len, str);
  return TCL_OK;
}

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp* interp)
{
  if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR)
    return TCL_ERROR;
  Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp,"prtstr", PrintStrObjCmd, (ClientData) NULL, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) NULL);
  return TCL_OK;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char       *script = argv[1];
  Tcl_Obj    *argvPtr;
  Tcl_FindExecutable(script);

  Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
  if (interp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot create TCL interpreter\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (Tcl_AppInit(interp) != TCL_OK)
    return TCL_ERROR;

  Tcl_SetVar2Ex(interp, "argv0", NULL, Tcl_NewStringObj(script,-1), TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
  argc -= 2;
  argv += 2;
  Tcl_SetVar2Ex(interp, "argc", NULL, Tcl_NewIntObj(argc), TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
  argvPtr = Tcl_NewListObj(0, NULL);
  while (argc--) 
    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(NULL, argvPtr, Tcl_NewStringObj(*argv++, -1));
  Tcl_SetVar2Ex(interp, "argv", NULL, argvPtr, TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);

  if (Tcl_EvalFile(interp, script) != TCL_OK)
    return TCL_ERROR;

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: "so if I want a fresh value of the interpreter, I'll have to delete the old one and create a new one everytime." Yes and no, you don't have to obtain a fresh main interpreter from within C for each step; you can manage the lifecycle from within your script (`tryMe.tcl`) using a child or slave interpreter:  `set slave [interp create]; $slave eval {prtstr "Test from tryMe.tcl"}; interp delete $slave`

Comment: True that you can create a child interpreter to avoid having to create/delete the main interpreter in the C code but with my measurements it is slower.  Keep C interpreter/create delete in TCL child interp = 1.7 seconds.  Fresh C interp 1.1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [the Tcler's Wiki on this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+to+embed+Tcl+in+C+applications), as the pattern of embedding a Tcl interpreter in your application is a known and supported one. It includes a worked example that you can adapt (and no, I didn't write it; I prefer to extend standard Tcl interpreters).

The main problem you've got is that you're not calling `Tcl_FindExecutable()`. In modern Tcl, that initialises a number of key subsystems in the library (including its high-performance memory allocator!) so it's slightly vital. In your case, you've got a real `argv` available so you can use `argv[0]` with it:

```
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
// NULL would also work as an argument, in a pinch at least
```

Once you've done that, you can call other Tcl API functions, specifically `Tcl_CreateInterp()`.

You have a minor problem in that you are not testing the results of calls for failure. In C, this is *essential* as you don't have exceptions to do the heavy lifting of error handling for you.